# Using the object Silex/Application into a Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, composer-php, silex

I need to use a third party API into a Symfony2 app, which is using composer to manage dependencies.
This API is built using Silex, so I need to use a Silex/Application object.

I have manage to get silex by adding

```
"silex/silex": "1.0.*"
```

into composer.json, but when I specify

```
use Silex/Application
```

in the controller and

```
  $app = new Silex\Application();
```

in the action where I want to manage the third party API, the response is:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'MyApp\MyBundle\MyController\Silex\Application' not found in path\to\my\controller\MyController.php on line 130

It seems like the Silex namespace haven't been loaded.

Any idea about how can I manage to use Silex into Symfony2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exported it as `use Silex\Application;` then `$app = new Application();`
or `use Silex\Application as SilexApp` then `$app = new SilexApp();`